# MvvmCross Show(intent) not available anymore

Tags: android, mvvmcross, back-stack

We use a ViewPresenter to clear the backstack. The code below was used to achieve that and it worked well. Since MvvmCross 5.2 the Show(intent) no longer exists. What should we use instead?

```
public class ViewPresenter : MvxAndroidViewPresenter
{
    public override void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        if (request != null && request.PresentationValues != null)
        {
            if (request.PresentationValues.ContainsKey(ShowViewParameters.ClearBackstack.ToString()))
            {
                // Get intent from request and set flags to clear backstack.
                var intent = base.CreateIntentForRequest(request);
                intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTask | ActivityFlags.NewTask);

                base.Show(intent);
                return;
            }
        }

        base.Show(request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've programmed now and it works fine:

```
public class ViewPresenter : MvxAndroidViewPresenter
{
    public ViewPresenter(IEnumerable<Assembly> androidViewAssemblies) : base(androidViewAssemblies)
    {
    }

    public override void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        var intent = base.CreateIntentForRequest(request);

        if (request != null && request.PresentationValues != null)
        {
            if (request.PresentationValues.ContainsKey(ShowViewParameters.ClearBackstack.ToString()))
            {
                // Get intent from request and set flags to clear backstack.
                intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTask | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            }
        }

        ShowIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: This means you cannot use all the new features in Mvx 5.2. Only use `ShowIntent` inside your inner if and return. After that do base.Show()

Comment: Could you elaborate on why I should use the Show() instead of the ShowIntent()?

Comment: As i said: so you can use the new features: https://www.mvvmcross.com/mvvmcross-52-release/#a-new-default-android-presenter-1934

You can still use ShowIntent in your inner if so your own code stays working.